How to achieve in-memory caching technique with two azure instances
We have an asp.net mvc application hosted on azure with 2 instances. Recently we are trying to implement in-memory caching technique. But it is storing cache in 2 servers differently(not consistent). Can someone help on this please without using Redis Cache.
To achieve in-memory technique system.runtime.caching with 2 azure instances

Do you need it to be consistent across systems? So is it more then a cache?

An option would be to rewrite Redis and call it differently or take a product that does the same but is not called Redis?

Yes it needs to be consistent across system

Im checking for a solution if we can achieve in-memory caching technique without using Redis Cache service

If you want a distributed local cache, consistent and not just eventually consistent your presumably out of luck.

Please have a look at Azure Architecture Center, it is such a valuable resource for questions like these.
Your caching options (or better: the caching best practices) are described in the Caching guidance article under Best practices for cloud applications.

Caching in distributed applications
Distributed applications typically implement either or both of the following strategies when caching data:

They use a private cache, where data is held locally on the computer that's running an instance of an application or service.
They use a shared cache, serving as a common source that can be accessed by multiple processes and machines.

In both cases, caching can be performed client-side and server-side. Client-side caching is done by the process that provides the user interface for a system, such as a web browser or desktop application. Server-side caching is done by the process that provides the business services that are running remotely.

It's a very extensive article that even holds code samples for specific types of implementations.
